# correct way for using joins when use len() sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I need to **join** one or two tables. One table have salary field. So i make some calculations also if the field is null means it returns 0. So I use **len()**. But i can't access the correct values. when i use join before **len()** condition i have a result. But result id column comes unorder like **1,4,46,89,**...something like that. I don't know why.

**My query is,**

```
 CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(o.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', o.Budget))*100000

 + SUBSTRING(CAST(o.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', o.Budget) + 4, 
    patindex('%Thousands%', o.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', o.Budget) - 4)* 1000 AS   VARCHAR(50))+')'

    FROM requirementsdetailsfororganization o 
    right Join Requirementsregistereddetails AS r ON r.registereddate=r.registereddate
    left join Requirement_Contact_Details as rc ON rc.RequirementID=o.requirementId
    **where len(o.Budget)<>0**
```

In the above code where i starred this condition i used. But why it shows this types of values.

**MY output:**

Insert into jobs(**1**,85000)

Insert into jobs(**3**,205000)

Insert into jobs(**4**,0(when null))

Insert into jobs(**16**,145000)

Insert into jobs(**18**,110000)

In the previous result, what i bold the values are Id. It is unordered and some values are missed within the range of values when i use len()

Any one suggest me my issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
 CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(o.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', o.Budget))*100000

 + SUBSTRING(CAST(o.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', o.Budget) + 4, 
    patindex('%Thousands%', o.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', o.Budget) - 4)* 1000 AS   VARCHAR(50))+')'

    FROM requirementsdetailsfororganization o 
    right Join Requirementsregistereddetails AS r ON r.registereddate=r.registereddate
    left join Requirement_Contact_Details as rc ON rc.RequirementID=o.requirementId
    where len(isnull(o.Budget, ":D"))<>0
```

Comment: what is that ":D"? and also this is not correct way. All related columns also get NULL when budget Null.

Comment: Did you even test my query?

Comment: Why do you do a right join if you're rejecting null values for requirementsdetailsfororganization columns?